# Import Flask syntax error message

Tags: python, templates, flask

What could be wrong here? I am trying to put together an app in Python that would send survey data that would be input on a form on a website to an email address which would work with a webpage that is written in html.

Error Message:

```
  File "/Users/msk/bssproject/sendmail.py", line 2
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

sendmail.py:

```
@app.route("/Users/msk/bssproject/Flask-0.10")
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash import flask.views
from flask.forms import ContactForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail

mail = Mail()

app = Flask(__name__)

mail.init_app(app)

app.config.update( 
DEBUG = True, 
MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com', 
MAIL_PORT = 465, 
MAIL_USE_TLS = False, 
MAIL_USE_SSL = True, 
MAIL_USERNAME = 'username@gmail.com', 
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'password')

mail = Mail(app)

def send_email():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash('All fields are required')
        return render_template('feedback.html', form=form)
    else:
        msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='mlkrgr@gmail.com', recipients=['mlkrgr@gmail.com'])
        msg.body = "feedback.html"      
        send (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
        mail.send(msg)
    return 'Form posted'

class Submit(flask.views.MethodView):
    def post(self):
        send_email()
        return flask.render_template('thanks.html')

app.add_url_rule('/',
        view_func=Submit.as_view('submit'),
        methods=["POST"])

app.run()
```

Comment: The issue is `@app.route("/Users/msk/bssproject/Flask-0.10")`.  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I am trying to specify the route in which Flask is in. If I do not put this line of code in, what is returned is:                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/msk/bssproject/sendmail.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
ImportError: No module named flask
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: You want to use `#!/Users/msk/bssproject/Flask-0.10/bin/python` (a guess based on your code) to specify the correct python installation to use.  This assumes you used virtualenv to install python at `/Users/msk/bssproject/Flask-0.10`.  The `app.route` decorator is for specifying request routes for the app.

Comment: You seem to not have a very limited grasp of how to use Python, let alone Flask, let alone Flask with the mail extension. That's okay, we were all once starting out. However, I think you're trying to do too much for someone of your experience level. Start smaller. First, just making sure flask is installed by running `python` and entering `import flask`. If flask is installed, nothing should happen. Otherwise, you'll get an error. Once you know it's installed, then try the very basic [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/#tutorial).

Comment: To add to what @MarkHildreth said, I would follow up the Flaskr tutorial with [The Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure Flask was installed in your PC
2. I think the problem is while you make a router

You can test with this

```
@app.route("/home")

def home():
__ ....    
__ ....    
__ return
```